# maven ignores alternate pom

Tags: maven, tycho

When I use mvn like so:

`c:\Users\me\git\repo> mvn -f pom-ext.xml clean verify`

It refuses to pick up that pom. It runs the `pom.xml` in the same directory. If I delete the `pom.xml` the build fails.

When I rename `pom-ext.xml` to `pom.xml` the build runs fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\Users\me\Programs\mvn\bin..
Java version: 11.0.7, vendor: Eclipse OpenJ9, runtime: C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.7.10-openj9
Default locale: nl_NL, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: does have your pom "pom" packaging? <packaging>pom</packaging>

Comment: @imperezivan yes

Comment: `mvn -f pom-ext.xml clean verify` should work. Just verified it locally. Most likely a typo. You could try `set MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO=on` for analysis.

Comment: @RobertScholte no typo I'm afraid. I'm not a (total) noob. Last message in that MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO=on list is:

"C:\pathtojava\java.exe"  -classpath "C:\Users\me\Programs\mvn\bin\..\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar"  "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Users\me\Programs\mvn\bin\..\bin\m2.conf"   "-Dmaven.home=C:\Users\me\Programs\mvn\bin\.."   "-Dlibrary.jansi.path=C:\Users\me\Programs\mvn\bin\..\lib\jansi-native"   "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\me\git\temp\miworkplace" org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -f pom-ext.xml clean verify

But it still drops in pom.xml

Comment: is there a space in one of the paths? Is it a specific plugin that fails?